# Have MySQL return JSON keys which themselves contain certain values

Tags: mysql, sql, json

The problem I am trying to solve is to have a MySQL query return the Keys within a JSON that has the value "stage":"Functioning". I've been trying to work this problem out for a while now but can't find a solution.

It's worth adding as well that there will be several JSONs within the database table.

One of the JSONs is as follows:

```
{
  "1493510400":{
    "stage":"Resting",
    "dateAltered":"true"
  },
  "1508716800":{
    "stage":"Functioning",
    "dateAltered":"true"
  },
  "1522713600":{
    "stage":"Functioning",
    "dateAltered":"true",
    "stageAltered":"true"
  },
  "1537315200":{
    "stage":"Functioning",
    "stageAltered":"true"
  },
  "1551916800":{
    "stage":"Resting",
    "stageAltered":"true"
  },
  "1566518400":{
    "stage":"Resting",
    "stageAltered":"true"
  },
  "1581120000":{
    "stage":"Functioning"
  },
  "1595721600":{
    "stage":"Resting"
  }
}
```

Each level has a timestamp as its key. Within each level, there will always be a value for 'stage'. These are only ever going to be Resting or Functioning. From here, I need to create a query that will return all the keys (timestamps) that have a value "stage":"Functioning".

I've got `SELECT JSON_KEYS(field_value)` working fine and it returns an array of the timestamps but when I try adding on some `WHERE` statements, it fails to return anything.

Some of the queries I've tried are:

- `SELECT JSON_KEYS(field_value) WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(field_value, '$*.stage') = 'Functioning'`
- `SELECT JSON_KEYS(field_value) WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(field_value, '{"stage":"Functioning"}', '$.stage')`

I know I'm probably being an idiot here so apologies if this feels like a waste of time to people but I'm totally stumped right now.

Is what I'm trying to accomplish even possible within MySQL?

My current version of MySQL is **5.7.22**

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide better example data with table structure? Place it on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or https://www.db-fiddle.com/.. And expected results as formatted text

Comment: Hi Raymond, thanks for the reply. Here's the link to db-fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nB5gKjsGQYKRZCiUEKJRQR/2

As you can see, the query is outputting all the JSON keys (timestamps). From here, what I want to do is only output the keys that have a value within of 'Functioning'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your version doesn't support that functionality. If you can upgrade to MySQL 8.0.11, you can use [JSON_TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html), [JSON_SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)  or something similar, depending on your individual case (honestly no clue what exactly you want to achieve based on your post).

Comment: Ok I'll look into that. Thanks for your response